# Why is it defined as a constructor? java

Tags: java

could anyone explain what makes it a constructor? why is it described as a constructor? (line 4)

```
1.    public class Square 
2.    {
3.     private int length;
4.      public Square () 
5.      {
6.        length = 0;
7.       }
8.      public void setLength(int l)
9.       {
10.    length = l;
11.   }
12.  public int getLength ()
13.   {
14.    return length;
15.   }
16. }
```

Comment: Not understanding what your question is

Comment: either. but try to study here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Constructor contains necessary data required to construct your object.

Comment: Did you even try to find out for yourself what a constructor is, before posting your question here?

Comment: Please first understand basic things your self. Try to post more valuable question here. First search and find what is Constructor is and what it does. There are lot of tutorials in the internet.  Please refer [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html).

Comment: Looks like a blatant dump of a homework question -- in the future, please show a little initiative.

Answer (score 0):

It has no return type, and it has the same name as the enclosing class. It is a constructor. If you don't want it to be one

```
public void Square() // <-- a method (with a name that doesn't follow
                     //     naming conventions).
```

On the other hand, if you want to know when a constructor is used, then they are invoked when someone instantiates an instance of `Square` with `new Square()`.

[JLS-8.8. Constructor Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) says (in part),

> A *constructor* is used in the creation of an object that is an instance of a class ([§12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), [§15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)).

and

> The `SimpleTypeName` in the `ConstructorDeclarator` must be the simple name of the class that contains the constructor declaration; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.
>
> In all other respects, the constructor declaration looks just like a method declaration that has no result ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)).